# Bayer to HSV using openCV

Tags: opencv, color-space

does somebody know is there is a function somewhere available (based on OpenCV), to convert bayer images to HSV colourspace? 
Or do I have to do the step via RGB?

Answer (score 1):

Read about cvtColor and CV_BayerBG2BGR. More [here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/miscellaneous_image_transformations.html).